# how do i stop a looped sound effect from stopping when another sound is played c#

Tags: c#

I am playing background music using

```
SoundPlayer bgMusic = new SoundPlayer(@"bgmusic.wav");
```

then

```
bgMusic.PlayLooping();
```

but if I try to play any other sounds the music stops, is there a way to keep it going without using another thread

Comment: `bgMusic.Stop()`. It is always a good idea and the fastest way to read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.playlooping?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Media_SoundPlayer_PlayLooping) and the remarks/samples.

Answer (score 0):

You ought not use SoundPlayer Class for this work; SoundPlayer is a lightweight class for playing occasional incidental sounds in an application. It will occasionally remove sounds if other things are going on in the audio subsystem (like a music playing).  [(WaveOutPlayer)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3352/A-low-level-audio-player-in-C) API solve your problem.